# Android Paho + CloudMQTT EOFException as soon as I connect

Tags: android, eclipse, mqtt, paho

At a complete loss here, but as soon as I attempt to connect to CloudMQTT, my client crashes.

> 3-05 16:22:54.541 9063-9078/my.pkg.name D/MQTTCONN: About to connect
>
> 03-05 16:22:55.341 9063-9091/my.pkg.name D/AlarmPingSender: Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttServiceourTestMqttSubId
>
> 03-05 16:22:55.375 9063-9063/my.pkg.name E/MQTTFAIL: Connection lost
>
> 03-05 16:22:55.376 9063-9063/my.pkg.name W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:146)
>
> 03-05 16:22:55.377 9063-9063/my.pkg.name W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:65)
>
> 03-05 16:22:55.377 9063-9063/my.pkg.name W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:107)

Here is my code:

```
final MqttAndroidClient mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(
    argsService.getContext(),
    (String) configService.getArg("mqttBroker"),
    activeSubId.getSubId(),
    new MemoryPersistence()
);

MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setCleanSession(true);
options.setUserName((String) configService.getArg("mqttUser"));
options.setPassword(((String) configService.getArg("mqttPassword")).toCharArray());
options.setConnectionTimeout(9999);

Log.d("MQTTCONN", "About to connect");
mqttClient.connect(options, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
        Log.d("MQTTCONN", "Connect ready");
        mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                // Someday, in case we want to recover our service
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                receiveMessageIntent.enact(
                    new JSONObject(new String(message.getPayload())),
                    pubsub
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

            }
        });

        try {
            mqttClient.subscribe(getSubId().getSubId(), QOS);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
        Log.e("MQTTFAIL", exception.getMessage());
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Troubleshooting I've already tried:

- Setting the appropriate Android permissions right above opening my `application` tag in the Manifest (but I'm not using persistence, so it just needs internet)
- Setting MQTT version to `MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1`
- Trying `ssl://` with CloudMQTT's SSQL 2XXXX port
- Restarting CloudMQTT Instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To somebody who may stumble on this in the future - MQTT is a fairly simple, hassle free protocol to setup. Issues like this are most likely at the server side.

In my case, it was most likely **CloudMQTT's Free Tier connection/usage limitations** that caused this issue. After much time spent trying to figure the guts of Paho out, I simply spun up my own Mosquitto Instance using a handy Ansible role and AWS, and things worked out swell like they should have hours ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use CloudMQTT as a broker but I had an issue with a different broker (RabbitMQ) where this happened.  It turned out after changing the TTL for durable (qos1+) queues, I had to delete all existing queues and let the clients re-create them.  Presumably changing the clientid would have worked as well.